# Is it advisable to call abstract methods from a method in that Abstract Class

Tags: design-patterns, abstract-class, object-oriented-analysis

I have been wondering about this for a long time.

I have to perform this process -

```
process(){
   bool allow=checkForPermission();
   if(allow) {
      processRequest();
   }
   sendResponse();
}
```

Now I have made an abstract Class X with three abstract methods:

```
abstract class X {
   public abstract sendResponse();
   public abstract checkPermission();
   public abstract sendResponse();
   public abstract example(); // some example which is called from sendResponse() from where it is implemented.

   public void process() {
      bool allow=checkForPermission();
      if(allow) {
         processRequest();
      }
      sendResponse();
   }
}
```

Class A extends X; this is where I am uncertain. When A is implementing all the abstract methods, and in sendResponse() method it is making a call to IfError() Function, is it a good design?

My friend suggests this: Its like compiler will first call X.process() then to A implemented methods, and again A to X (where sendResponse() will call example() method), which my friend said is not a good design:

```
X obj = new A();
obj.process();
```

Will it be a good design?

Comment: This sounds like the Template Pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly fine, except for some points:

- if the abstract methods are only supposed to be called from inside the `process()` method, and not indepenently, from any other outside class, then they should be protected, not public.
- if the subclasses are not supposed to change the implementation of `process()`, because every process must follow this template, then the `process()` method should be final
- if the `example()` method is not supposed to be called from an outside class, but only as part of the implementation of sendResponse() in subclasses, then it has no reason to exist in the base class. `sendResponse()` is already abstract, and the subclass is thus free to implement it the way it wants to. So forcing it to also implement an `example()` method that is not used anywhere is useless.

Answer (score 1):

This is an acceptable pattern, though sometimes it indicates that you're mixing implementation with interface.

It may be better instead to have two or more classes/interfaces, and a "driver" class:

```
class DriverX {
   RequestProcessor  requestProcessor;
   ResponseSender    responseSender;
   PermissionChecker permissionChecker;

   public void process() {
      if (permissionChecker.checkPermission()) {
         requestProcessor.processRequest();
      }
      responseSender.sendResponse();
   }
}
```

Where the referenced types are interfaces.

This provides a clear separation of responsibilities. This makes it easier to unit-test, easier to document, more flexible (if permission checking might differ but the response sender is reusable).